# Problems with laravel breeze

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, breeze

I'm new to laravel and need a little advice,

I tried to install laravel brezze with :
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
artisan breeze: install

on an already existing project, and it removes all my `web` routes that I already had before to replace them with these:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

I no longer have access to the page I have already created, is there a possibility to install breeze without deleting the routes already created?

Also when I want to run my npm install and run dev I have this error

````
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'postcss-import'
Require stack:
- webpack.mix.js
- laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
- node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/webpack.mix.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (//node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/webpack.mix.js',
    '/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js',
    '/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}```


I remember that this is the first time I use breeze so I looked at the docs but I may not understand how it works

Thank you!
````

Comment: Add your removed route from your backup. laravel breeze added auth.php route file in web.php. Breeze just replaced its web file with your.

Comment: `postcss-import` not found in package.json.

Comment: You have to install postcss-import by `npm install postcss-import` and other module if required

Comment: ok thanks for all your answers, the npm install postcss-import has worked.