# Laravel route removed automatically when i installed breeze

Tags: php, laravel

so i was installing breeze in my device and all my routes got deleted by itself. I didnt do anything and it got deleted by itslelf. can someone plz help me?

i tried a lot to get all those code back but failed.later on the breeze got installed but i am not able to find my code .

Comment: I think that you didn't pushed your codes to GIT. Most IDEs like PhpStorm, Visual Studio Code, etc., keep a local history of files. You might still be able to retrieve a previous version of your routes file from your IDE's local history. Try to research about your ide local history.

Comment: Its common issue when you install breeze. as when you use breeze:install command the breeze will remove all the routes from web.php and replace it with default dashboard routes. I dont think there is anything you can do unless you have code backups. The only way to avoid that is to use seperate route file for your own routes. like create users.php and admin.php with their relevent routes in it and then including it in web.php file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a GitHub issue from last year about this: [Breeze starter kit installation removed contents of route file web.php instead of appending auth routes](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/41739).  It concludes with: *Breeze is intended for new Laravel applications, not existing ones. You should never install Breeze in an existing app.*

According to this, the answer is: you cannot get your code back unless you had back-up.

However you may also look at

- previous report here on Stack Overflow with possible answer in comments: [Problems with laravel breeze](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69705126/12846804)
- short discussion in [Laracasts forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-fix-the-problem-of-removing-routes-after-installing-the-package)